# Copy and empty arrays to a certain size

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have 8 arrays that contain many elements.

I would like to know what I can do to copy these elements into a new array when the array's size is 50?

I have:

```js
const buf = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64");
const acc_dx = [0, 2, 4].map(index => buf.readInt16LE(index));
this.arrayAccelerationRight.push([this.timeS, ...acc_dx].join(":"));
```

When the length is 50 I would like to copy the elements into a new array (`arrayAccelerationRightCopy`) and empty the original one (`arrayAccelerationRight`). When the length will be 50 I would like to do the same things, copying the elements in the same array (`arrayAccelerationRightCopy`).

How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: To copy an array, use `const copy = arr.slice();` and to empty an array, use `arr = []`(just set it to an empty array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `Array.splice` :

```js
const size = 50;

// Create a sample array from 1 to 60
const arrayAccelerationRight = Array.from({length: 60}, (_, i) => i + 1);

while(arrayAccelerationRight.length >= size) {
  const arrayAccelerationRightCopy = arrayAccelerationRight.splice(0, size);
  
  console.log(arrayAccelerationRight);
  console.log(arrayAccelerationRightCopy);
}
```